# What is the syntax of package.jdo file for a self referential table

Tags: java, oracle, jdo

I have a self referential table that I am mapping with kodo jdo 4 (supplied from weblogic server 10.3.4.) The code I have will get through the enhancer, but when I try to use it I get the error:

```
<openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:965591 fatal user error> kodo.jdo.FatalUserException: Missing table name for field "com.[...].jdo.Branch.branches". This field cannot reside in the owning class table.
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.mapJoin(FieldMapping.java:529)
```

the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE branch 
(
id              VARCHAR2(10)   NOT NULL,
parentId        VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL,
[other fields deleted ...]
CONSTRAINT branch_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT branch_fk_parent FOREIGN KEY(parentId) REFERENCES branch(id)
);
```

the class is :

```
public class Branch implements MenuPart, Serializable
{
private Branch parent;
    private Set<Branch> branches = new HashSet<Branch> ();
    private String id;
    private Set<Leaf> leafs = new HashSet<Leaf> ();
    private long ordering;
    private String title;
    //methods removed.
}
```

the package.jdo file is:

```
    <class name="Branch" objectid-class="BranchId" table="SCHEMA.BRANCH">
        <version strategy="none"/>
        <field name="parent" table="SCHEMA.BRANCH">
                <column name="SCHEMA.BRANCH.PARENTID" target="ID" />
        </field>
        <field name="branches" table="SCHEMA.BRANCH" >
            <collection element-type="Branch"/>
            <join>  
                <column name="SCHEMA.BRANCH.PARENTID" target="ID" />
            </join>
        </field>
        <field name="id" column="ID" primary-key="true"/>
        <field name="leafs" table="SCHEMA.LEAF">
            <collection element-type="Leaf"/>
              <join>  
                <column name="ID" target="BRANCHID" />
      </join>
        </field>
        <field name="ordering" column="ORDERING"/>
        <field name="title" column="TITLE"/>
    </class>
```

I have gotten the functionality to work in kodo jdo 3.4 but now the syntax is different and the friendly manual isn't that helpful that I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what finally worked

```
    <class name="Branch" objectid-class="BranchId" table="EBIGP.BRANCH">
        <version strategy="none"/>
        <field name="parent">
            <column name="EBIGP.BRANCH.PARENTID" target="ID" />
        </field>
        <field name="branches" mapped-by="parent" />
        <field name="id" column="ID" primary-key="true"/>
        <field name="leafs" default-fetch-group="true">
            <collection element-type="Leaf"/>
            <element column="BRANCHID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ordering" column="ORDERING"/>
        <field name="title" column="TITLE"/>
    </class>
```

Apparently all it needed was a **mapped-by="parent"** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its objecting to you defining the join-table for that relation to be the table for the class itself (which is obviously wrong).

Obviously Kodo is not fully JDO-compliant, and is dead as a project, so if you hit issues then you've got problems ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
<class name="Branch" objectid-class="BranchId" table="SCHEMA.BRANCH">
    <version strategy="none"/>
    <field name="parent" table="SCHEMA.BRANCH">
            <column name="SCHEMA.BRANCH.PARENTID" target="ID" />
    </field>
    <field name="branches" table="SCHEMA.BRANCH" >
        <collection element-type="Branch"/>
        <extension vendor-name="kodo" key="inverse-owner" value="parent"/>
    </field>
    <field name="id" column="ID" primary-key="true"/>
</class>
```

Comment: That ought to work but there is a bug in oracle (13498102)  that fails in the JDO only file case. It can be made to work with both jdo and ORM files.